# Add a second legend in the plot in R

Tags: r, statistics, ggplot2

I got the default legend based on a factor of a column. I colored the x-axis based on a factor of another column.

Can I add a legend for this x-axis color as well?

[image]

Merged Data( https://dl.dropbox.com/u/81597211/Untitled.pdf)

```
row.names   LCA_CASE_WORKLOC1_CITY  LCA_CASE_JOB_TITLE  LCA_CASE_WORKLOC1_STATE LCA_CASE_WAGE_RATE_FROM Company
    4726    REDWOOD SHORES  SOFTWARE DEVELOPER - ARCHITECT  CA  263500.00   ORACLE
    102663  DENVER  SOFTWARE ENGINEER (SOFTWARE DEVELOPER 5)    CO  170000.00   ORACLE
    103621  DENVER  SOFTWARE ENGINEER (SOFTWARE DEVELOPER 5)    CO  170000.00   ORACLE
    95210   SANTA CLARA SOFTWARE ENGINEER (SOFTWARE DEVELOPER 4)    CA  155000.00   ORACLE
    18858   SANTA CLARA SOFTWARE ENGINEER (CONSULTING SOLUTION DIRECTOR)    CA  150000.00   ORACLE
    19514   IRVING  CONSULTING TECHNICAL MANAGER    TX  150000.00   ORACLE
    57054   REDWOOD SHORES  SOFTWARE ENGINEER (SOFTWARE DEVELOPER 4)    CA  150000.00   ORACLE
    76335   REDWOOD SHORES  SOFTWARE ENGINEER (APPLICATIONS DEVELOPER 4)    CA  150000.00   ORACLE
    79964   REDWOOD SHORES  SOFTWARE ENGINEER (SOFTWARE DEVELOPER 5)    CA  150000.00   ORACLE
```

Code

```
library("ggplot2")
colour = factor(merged$Company)
xcolor = factor(merged$LCA_CASE_WORKLOC1_STATE)
qplot(merged[[2]], merged[[4]], colour = colour, xlab="Positions", ylab ="Salary", main="H1B Salary 2012") + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,vjust=0.5, hjust=1, size=10, color= xcolor, lineheight=10)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,300000, 10000)) + theme(panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "red", linetype = "dotted")) + scale_x_discrete(merged[[2]])
```

Comment: Can you show the code you used to generate this (preferably in a reproducible example?)

Comment: @David : I have attached the dataframe. Are you still getting problems with the data?

Comment: @kunj2aan, when you copy this exactly what you've pasted on a new R-session, are you able to get the plot without errors?

Comment: @Arun, what errors are you seeing?

Comment: `Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:colour`

Comment: With the new data you've pasted here: `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`

Comment: There are (somewhat difficult) ways around it, but the basic answer is no. You cannot have more than one color scale. This is a design choice that is built into ggplot2. As I said, there are hacks to get around it, but it won't be straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is not as versatile as we might want, but also it is not very difficult and technical. First some data:

```
y <- c(5, 2, 3, 2)
x <- factor(c("A", "B", "C", "A"))
z <- factor(c("D", "E", "F", "E"))

p <- qplot(x, y, geom = "point") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = z))
```

A popular function `g_legend` (can be found e.g. [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Share-a-legend-between-two-ggplot2-graphs)) is useful in this case, it takes a legend from a plot as a grob (hence this solution is not fast).

```
g_legend<-function(a.gplot){
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  legend
}
```

So we save two legends, one for the points (`x`) and one for the x-axis (`z`).

```
legends <- list(g_legend(p + geom_point(aes(color = x))),
                g_legend(p + geom_point(aes(color = z)) + 
                          scale_color_manual(values = palette()[as.numeric(z)])))
```

Notice a difference in the second legend. `palette()` is used here because if e.g. `z <- factor(c(1, 2, 3))` then `element_text(color = z)` uses different colors than `geom_point(aes(color = z))`, i.e. `element_text(color = z)` takes colors from base plot as e.g. 2 in `plot(1, col = 2)`.

Finally, putting everything together:

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p + geom_point(aes(color = x)) + guides(color = 'none'), 
             do.call(arrangeGrob, legends), nrow = 1, widths = c(0.8, 0.2))
```

[image]